Azure Functions & Application Insights requests "Operation Link" empty
We upgraded Azure Functions to Isolated and .NET 8. After doing so we are seeing Service Bus requests in Application Insights having the request property "Operation links" being basically empty
Operation links [{"operation_Id":"00000000000000000000000000000000","id":"0000000000000000"}]

This seems to result that in the end-to-end transaction view multiple requests are thrown together



In our Function we are configuring application insights the following program.cs
.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
{
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
    services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
    {
        // The Application Insights SDK adds a default logging filter that instructs ILogger to capture only Warning and more severe logs. Application Insights requires an explicit override.
        // Log levels can also be configured using appsettings.json. For more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service#ilogger-logs
        LoggerFilterRule? ruleToRemove = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");

        if (ruleToRemove is not null)
        {
            options.Rules.Remove(ruleToRemove);
        }
    });
 }


I would expect that I should only see one Request to Azure Service Bus. Cause this was the case with .NET 6 and in-process
Edit included .csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enabled</ImplicitUsings>
    <AnalysisLevel>latest-recommended</AnalysisLevel>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Analyzers" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Data.Tables" Version="12.9.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.22.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NetTopologySuite" Version="2.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.18.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.23.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.22.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="local.settings.json" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>


So the issue is you are getting duplicate entries for same request ?

They seem not to be duplicated. Different timestamps. But we see requests which should not be there as they belong to another operation id. The requests in that view go back multiple hours. App Insights for some reason aggregates those together by querying for multiple operation ids

Please share your configuration and .csproj file.

Added the .csproj file in the original post

Did you check whether you have same issue with new function app .net 8 isolated ?

Use custom telemetry to send the unique Operation id for each request.

All operation ids are unique. The issue is, that the custom dimension _MS.links is not promoted correctly.

If possible please share your code repo.

I can't share it

Plese provide more details,Unable to repro the issue from my end.

This issue was caused by an older Application Insights SDK on the API sending in the messages.
As the model of the in-process functions is different than the isolated functions. Digging way deeper down in the logs, showed that whenever the parent id started with "|" the operation link turned out to be set to 00000...  
So whenever there was a "|" in the parent id, the function completely jacked up the operational link.
Updating to the latest SDK on the API solves this issue.
